Having trouble making UserPrincipalName all lowercase in Powershell
I am trying to run a PowerShell script to change all UPNs in a specific OU to lowercase, but I am not having any success. Based on some previous posts and using the same command I use to change other attributes successfully, I am trying the following:
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=[REDACTED]" 
    | Set-ADUser -replace @{userPrincipalName=userPrincipalName.ToLower}

But when I run this I am getting an error

'userPrincipalName.ToLower' is not recognized

I have also tried adding () to the end of ToLower, but with the same result.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

You're missing a loop in your code to get the pipped user's UserPrincipalName, add ForEach-Object and reference it via $_.UserPrincipalName, then you can .ToLower() it:
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=[REDACTED]' | ForEach-Object {
    Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName.ToLower()
}


That did it! Thank you very much for the fix! I didn't consider that because with other attributes I mass-modify with a PS command I don't need the "ForEach" loop. For example, when I mass-modify the 'location' attribute I just do the pipe followed by the Set-ADUser and the replacement location. Thank you again!

@AA27CXP right but in this you need to know the user's upn in order to lower it, thus the need of the loop ;) glad it helped
